# Difference between junction points in old schematic

Tags: schematics, kicad, vintage

What's the difference between the black circle and the white one in this old schematic? Of course the black ones are junctions, but are the white circles a pin, or an input of some kind? I'm trying to redraw the circuit in KiCad but I can't find a way to express the "white" junction.

The attached picture is a Tone assembly of a vintage amplifier from the 70s.

[image: Tone assembly for vintage amplifier]

Comment: The circles are the terminals of the "potentiometer" component.  In KiCAD the terminals of a component are shown differently - the wire color is different from the component color, the component has pin numbers, etc.  There is no need to express the "circle" specifically.

Comment: As well as what others said re being potentiometer terminals - note eg RF14-CF10 which are connected in series do NOT have any intermediate dot (black or white). These and similar are quite possibly electrically and mechanically joined  "in the air" and have only two connection points either to pot tags or the PCB. | In the diagram in Transistor's answer the green LED at top left and the adjacent series resistor are connected in this manner - and the resistor then connects to a power input jack - also off the PCB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the hollow circles are only on the potentiometer connections. If the potentiometers are mounted off-board separate wires will be attached to those points.

[image]

*Figure 1. Off-board potentiometer wiring example. Image source: blog.mklec.com
Guitar Effects Pedal Offboard Wiring demystified. (This seems to be offline now.)*

On your PCB design I would use a pin connector symbol - maybe a pin header.

Comment: +1 . See my comment above starting as below. You may wish to add something along these lines for completeness. I could place an 'extra info' answer. but, having it all in one answer seems more useful long term. || I said " ... note eg RF14-CF10 which are connected in series do NOT have any intermediate dot (black or white). These and similar are quite possibly electrically and mechanically joined  "in the air" and have only two connection points either to pot tags or the PCB. | In the diagram in Transistor's answer the green LED at top left and the adjacent series resistor are connected ... "

Comment: Thanks, Russell, but the schematic is consistent with all other components being mounted on the board. Black dots have been used anywhere more than two components have been joined. RF14-CF10 which are connected in series don't require dots. Any in-the-air components would have been drawn in between the hollow dot and the potentiometer.

Comment: Looking at the circuit and your and my explanation I wot that Occam prefers mine to yours :-). | How would your photos's many airmounted connections be shown? (Genuine question). LED to R, R to pwr socket (maybe, deep-ending whether the Red Y-wire is as shown), switch self links, swouitch to power socket, power socket to input. switch to input, ....

Comment: In my world the in-the-air components would be between the hollow dot and the potentiometer. The red loop between pots 2 and 3 in the photo forms a 3-way connection so a black dot would be required there. The white dots are simply the board jump-off points.

Comment: In your world you would be correct! :-) - see image in my answer and link.

Comment: You are welcome to add reference or material from my answer if desired.

Answer (score 2):

This complements Transistor's correct answer.

As Transistor says, the white circles represent potentiometer terminals.
They happen to be "on board" in this case but that is not obvious from the diagram.
The manuals linked below show the correspondence between diagram and physical reality.

Here is an image of the PCB copper and component layout, plus your circuit.
[If you have this information available or any related information then providing it would help us greatly]. I have produced a negative image to make the tracks somewhat (but not very) more visible.

This is from the bottom of page 12 of
Marantz - [Mara 00177 - Service Manual 1072/1050](http://akdatabase.org/AKview/albums/userpics/10007/Marantz%201072%20and%201050%20Service%20Manual.pdf)

Also a less good version [here](http://s1.e-monsite.com/2009/09/24/41852962ampli-marantz-1072-pdf.pdf)

The diagram is smaller but *possibly* more legible [here](https://manualzz.com/doc/22438401/page-1-page-2-table-of-contents-section-page-1)

The potentiometers are in the four corners.
I have outlines RF10 & CF06 on both images to show how a series connection of 2 components is depicted on the circuit diagram.

[image]

Comment: +1 for good detective work. It's strange that they've used separate dots for the pots then if they're on-board. Looking at the manual, the tone control pots are sliders - hence the top and bottom connections at opposite ends of the board.

Comment: @Transistor  Agh. Of course. I wondered at the strange pinout of the pots. I didn't worry it to death enough! :-). The slider-pot  footprints are now wholly obvious.

Comment: I would say that the white circles indicate off-board connections in general, not just the potentiometer connections - see the row of white circles at the top of the schematic.

Comment: @PeterBennett It's semi arbitrary - the pots are "on board" but large. The connector leads to off board circuitry but is hardly larger than the resistors. || You could equally interpret it as RC / Other. Occasm can't decide :-).

Comment: Thank you so much for such a good discussion! Yeah, that's the right manual and PCB indeed. It's the circuit for a Marantz 1050 audio amplifier, which I also have at home. Unfortunately I haven't completely removed the PF00 board. I can add a photo of the back of the circuit, if that would help. And @Transistor is right, the tone control pots are sliders on the faceplate of the amp.